# Mercurial log - differentiate between added / modified / deleted files

Tags: mercurial

I use `hg log` with a template  :

`hg log -r : --template "{rev} | {date|shortdate} | {desc|strip|firstline}\n{files % '  - {file}\n'}\n"`

The output is :

```
1 | 2014-03-03 | first commit
  - doc/file1.txt
  - doc/file2.txt

2 | 2014-03-03 | second commit
  - data/img1.jpg
  - doc/file1.txt
  - doc/file2.txt
```

I want to differentiate between files that have been added(+)/modified(~)/deleted(-) instead of showing everything starting with a hyphen. Is that possible?

Something like :

```
1 | 2014-03-03 | first commit
  + doc/file1.txt
  + doc/file2.txt

2 | 2014-03-03 | second commit
  + data/img1.jpg
  ~ doc/file1.txt
  - doc/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{files}` has three equivalents, `{file_adds}`, `{file_dels}` and `{file_mods}`. So you can get there by changing

```
{files % '  - {file}\n'}
```

to

```
{file_adds % '  + {file}\n}\n{file_mods % '  ~ {file}\n}\n{file_dels % '  - {file}\n}`.
```

Comment: +1 for the help ! Thanks. I'll merge my answer with yours & accept it